# Add values to file with coordinates calculation

Tags: awk

Columns 4 and 5 are X and Y coordinates, column 6 is the elevation

I would like to add 2 new columns at the end of the file with values

- the distance between first(X)(Y) and last location (X)(Y)
- the diference in elevation = ($6-prev6)

How to calculate the requested values and add to last columns, and when the records appears only 1 time, write values 0.00 0.00

**Input file**

```
48047 41513  2  373512.79     2542085.84     154.53      12.64      90.63
48047 41513  3  373513.29     2542085.00     154.52      12.34      91.02
48047 41525  2  373663.51     2542087.65     153.93      12.36      90.70
48047 41525  3  373662.27     2542088.44     153.99      12.76      86.99
48049 39785  2  351912.93     2542112.25     160.91      12.16      90.61
48049 39797  2  352063.17     2542112.38     160.19      12.10      90.66
48049 39809  2  352213.12     2542113.01     159.96      12.24      90.75
```

**Desired Output**

```
48047 41513  2  373512.79     2542085.84     154.53      12.64      90.63
48047 41513  3  373513.29     2542085.00     154.52      12.34      91.02    0.98     0.01 
48047 41525  2  373663.51     2542087.65     153.93      12.36      90.70
48047 41525  3  373662.27     2542088.44     153.99      12.76      86.99    1.47     0.06
48049 39785  2  351912.93     2542112.25     160.91      12.16      90.61    0.00     0.00
48049 39797  2  352063.17     2542112.38     160.19      12.10      90.66    0.00     0.00
48049 39809  2  352213.12     2542113.01     159.96      12.24      90.75    0.00     0.00
```

My code works only when the records in columns 1 and 2 are duplicate. If they are not duplicate my code delete the single lines.

**Code I use to get the values**

```
 awk '{
       pp[NR]  = $2
       ll[NR]  = $1
        x[NR]  = $4
        y[NR]  = $5
          z[NR]  = $6
      } END {
               first = 1
               count = 0
               for ( i=1 ; i <= NR ; i++ ) {
                   if (pv[i] != pv[i+1] || line[i] != line[i+1]) {
                      last = i
                      count++
                      dx = x[first]-x[last]
                      dy = y[first]-y[last]
                      el = z[first]-z[last]
                      ele = sqrt(el^2)
                      len[count] = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)
                      if ( len[count] <= 1000 && len[count] > 0 ) {
                      printf ("%8.2f %8.2f \n",
                      len[count],ele)
                      }\
                      first = i+1
                  }
               }
              }' file
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) When you write _the end of the file_ you are probably referring to _the end of **the rows** of the file_. (2) The last two columns in your desired output miss the first and third rows; why? (3) What are _first_ and _last_ locations, with respect to the input file? (4) The _difference in the elevation_ of which rows? (5) In summary, could you improve the explanation of how you want to obtain those 2 columns?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis thanks to answer, 1) write the 2 new columns, 2) because the calculation of the distance is based in 2 rows (dx = x[first]-x[last]) (dy = y[first]-y[last]) (len[count] = sqrt(dx^2+dy^2)) 3) each 2 rows contends the xy coordinates 4) elevation is in column 6 el = z[first]-z[last] (ele = sqrt(el^2)) ..

Comment: Please, include your information in the question, not in the comments. However, I still don't understand. For instance, why is the last field in the third row of the output empty, intead of being `153.93 - 154.52`? Please, clarify. Or wait for someone who doesn't need clarifications, unlike me. Besides, the code you've posted doesn't generate any output; hint: what is `pv`, which is used in the `if` but never set?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, Thanks, I found the solution, check my answer .. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with

```
awk '
                {printf "%s" OFS, $0
                }
!M[$1,$2]       {print "0.00", "0.00"
                }
M[$1,$2]++      {print sqrt (($4-AX)^2 + ($5-AY)^2), $6 - AZ
                }
                {AX=$4
                 AY=$5
                 AZ=$6
                }
' OFS="\t" OFMT="%.2f" file
```

**output**

```
48047 41513  2  373512.79     2542085.84     154.53      12.64      90.63    0.00    0.00
48047 41513  3  373513.29     2542085.00     154.52      12.34      91.02    0.98    -0.01
48047 41525  2  373663.51     2542087.65     153.93      12.36      90.70    0.00    0.00
48047 41525  3  373662.27     2542088.44     153.99      12.76      86.99    1.47    0.06
48049 39785  2  351912.93     2542112.25     160.91      12.16      90.61    0.00    0.00
48049 39797  2  352063.17     2542112.38     160.19      12.10      90.66    0.00    0.00
48049 39809  2  352213.12     2542113.01     159.96      12.24      90.75    0.00    0.00
```